# Specify Key Vault URI in an AppSettin?

Tags: azure-keyvault

I have multiple instances of a web app (Azure App Services), they're all the same code, but are connected to client specific DBs.  So they're all deployed with the same web.config, but they have different connection strings and app settings, which I'm currently storing in the App Service's Configuration blade.

I want to move to using Key Vault instead.  I have it working on a test app, configured in the web.config like this:

```
<add name="AzureKeyVault" vaultName="my-vault" vaultUri="https://my-vault.vault.azure.net" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.AzureKeyVaultConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" /></builders>
```

However, I realise I'll need a Key Vault per instance of the app, yet each app's web config will then need to be different to hold the relevant vaultUri.

So my question is: is it possible to store the vaultUri in an AppSetting (stored in the App's Configuration blade) and somehow reference that in the configBuilder line, for example, something like this:

```
<add name="AzureKeyVault" vaultName="my-vault" vaultUri="[AppSetting.VaultName]" ...
```

Or, is there another way to achieve what I'm try to do - essentially reference a different Key Vault without requiring a different web.config for each app instance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you're asking how to get the key vault info from configuration blade -> web.config -> configbuilder code

If that's accurate, then I think you're overthinking this.  Go straight from configuaration blade -> configbuilder code.  Skip the web.config altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research you can add the **keyvault name** inside **appsettings.json**  Not the **URI**

example:

[image]

The use the provider, add a reference to the [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault/) package and add the following configuration to the startup code in **Program.cs**.

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
{
var root = config.Build();
config.AddAzureKeyVault(
$”https://{root["KeyVault:Vault"]}.vault.azure.net/",
root[“KeyVault:ClientId”],
root[“KeyVault:ClientSecret”]);
})
.UseStartup<Startup>();
```

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

And Also check with the [Configuration builders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/config-builder) provide a modern and agile mechanism for ASP.NET apps to get configuration values from external sources.

**Configuration builders** used to improve protection of configuration data by drawing from sources previously unavailable (for example, Azure Key Vault and environment variables) in the .NET configuration system